# Is Alpha Of An Index Fund Calculated Using Jensen's Measure?

Tags: investing, mutual-funds

Alpha is a commonly used metric to assess the returns of mutual funds (or other assets) over the expected return given the beta (volatility).

I have a specific doubt regarding alpha values computed for index funds.

From what I understand, there are two ways to measure alpha. Usual formula is this.

**Alpha = Ri - Beta x Rm**

Here, Ri stands for return from the index fund and Rm stands for the return from the benchmark index.

However, this formula does not include the Rf or risk free rate (typically 90 day treasury bill rate.)

Jensen's measure of alpha subtracts Rf from Ri and Rm during the calculation of alpha like this: (to isolate the effect of risky returns alone.)

**Jensen's Alpha = (Ri - Rf) - Beta x (Rm - Rf)**

Regarding the alpha values displayed in the financial websites, which of the above two "alphas" is used?